# Upgrade USN-3122-1: NVIDIA graphics drivers vulnerabilities : messes up graphics

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

The latest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS upgrade of 3 Nov 2016 destroys the graphics capabilities of some programs.
The old versions were

1. libcuda1-304.131
2. nvidia-304.131
3. nvidia-current.131
4. nvidia-libopencl1-304.131
5. nvidia-opencl-icd-304.131

and these worked just fine.

The new versions are:

1. libcuda1-304.132
2. nvidia-304.132
3. nvidia-current.132
4. nvidia-libopencl1-304.132
5. nvidia-opencl-icd-304.132

These show some strange side effects on the graphics in the following programs:

1. 0ad, shows the map, but no buildings, soldiers, trees or landscape features.
2. totem player, plays the movie all black in a black window, sound is ok.
3. possibly others I have not identified yet.

I can't find the nividia-*304.131 binaries, so I downgraded from 304.131-0ubuntu0.14.02.2 to 304.117.0ubuntu1 (trusty). 0ad and totem work again.

But I now have downgraded from nvidia-304.131, which was working fine, to nvidia-304.117. Any way to get nvidia-304.131 back again? and how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a problem with the Nvidia 304.132 driver, according https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/974456/f24-permission-problems-/?offset=2 .

It's also being reported at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321185/49753 and https://superuser.com/q/1141452/231111 and many other places. Apparently the only solution at the moment is to downgrade to the previous driver version (304.131).

You can find the 304.131 drivers for Ubuntu this way:

- go to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+publishinghistory
- look for the version you need, and click on the version number
- on the next page, look under "Builds" for your Ubuntu release, then click on the `amd64` or `i386` link behind the release name
- on the next page, look under "Built files" for the .deb file starting with "nvidia-304_304.131". Download that file.
- open a terminal and run "sudo dpkg -i *path-to-downloaded-.deb-file*" to install the downloaded version

Comment: it fixed the problem for me. later it's useful to lock this version of the package to prevent any updates: `sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-304`

Comment: With the `synaptic` package manager it is possible to force a package to a certain version.